# Sound through HDMI is intermittent when playing MP4 or MKV video using VLC or Videos

Tags: 14.04, sound, video, hdmi, vlc

I recently inherited a used Acer Aspire 6930g from a relative in the process of upgrading, and since it was almost worthless running Windows 7, I decided to put Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on it. Performance is significantly improved. I thought I'd hook it up to a Toshiba Regeza 47HL167 TV I have (almost as old as the Acer) through one of its many HDMI ports, so I could stream online vids on the big screen, and it works... most of the time.

On some videos, the sound through the TV speakers plays intermittently (on for about three seconds then off for three seconds approx.), and on other videos the sound plays perfectly. I also have downloaded video that I play using VLC, they are usually either MP4 or MKV, and on ALL of them the sound is always intermittent through the TV speakers. So what am I doing wrong here, other than trying to use a seriously old laptop to play videos on a large screen TV?

laptop = Acer Aspire 6930g
graphics processor = Intel GMA 4500MHD
TV = Toshiba Regeza 47HL167

running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

for online streaming using the version of Firefox that comes with the ubuntu install
for video on my pc using latest download of VLC

Let me kow if you need more info...

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I can confirm that it is a bug in Ubuntu 14.04 that affects audio output .Waiting for a solution .

Comment: sad now... From what I can glean through snurfling around, it appears this is an issue with 14.04 and didn't exist in earlier versions.  Thanks, even though it's not what I was hoping to learn.

Comment: You could upgrade to 15.10  or 16.04 when it is out next year.

Comment: Probably... in the meantime I can bypass hdmi output for audio by using speakers attached directly to the laptop, I can't imagine anything could go wrong with that. Just lacks 'tidiness'.

Comment: I have experienced the problem even on my speakers.

Comment: That's surprising. Using only the pc and watching through VLC, the sound is always good, so I thought setting the sound to stereo and outputting through analog speakers might bypass the issue, since the issue doesn't occur through the pc speakers. I have my desktop setup that way except the video goes to the monitor via DVI, and the speakers plugin to the back of the box through the audio output jack, and it works.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading BIOS to latest version, if not already? That helped me a lot (http://askubuntu.com/questions/614233/audio-via-nvidia-hdmi-skipping) - though it only made the skipping less worse, not go away completely.